# Providing one-time calculations to frequently used methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I'm new to JS/jQuery and wrote some JavaScript/jQuery lines to create a ["pulsating" object](http://jsfiddle.net/drkthng/RJWS2/9/).

I get the "pulse" effect by increasing/resizing the object and then bringing it back to its original state periodically.  I was uncomfortable with calculating the necessary values every time they are needed, so I used the first thing that came to my mind - global variables and only modify their values when the page is fully loaded.  But I also don't like that approach.

What is best practice in JavaScript/jQuery for this kind of problem, and how can I refactor my code accordingly?

Here is the code (JavaScript only, please see my link for HTML&CSS):

```
var elementOrigHeight;
var elementOrigWidth;
var elementIncreasedHeight;
var elementIncreasedWidth;
var elementNewTop;
var elementNewLeft;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#circle');
    var growInPercent = 100;
    setGlobalVariables(element, growInPercent);    
    var durationGetBigger = 500;
    var durationGetSmaller = 100;
    var frequency = 3;
    var pause = 3000;
    pulsate(element, durationGetBigger, durationGetSmaller,
    frequency, pause);
});

function pulsate(element, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
        getBigger(element, durationBigger);
        getSmaller(element, durationSmaller);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        pulsate(element, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause)
    }, pause);
}

function getBigger(element, duration) {
    element.animate({
        width: elementIncreasedWidth,
        height: elementIncreasedHeight,
        top: elementNewTop,
        left: elementNewLeft,
        opacity: 1
    }, duration, 'linear');
}

function getSmaller(element, duration) {
    element.animate({
        width: elementOrigWidth,
        height: elementOrigHeight,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: 0.5
    }, duration, 'linear');
}

function setGlobalVariables(element, percent) {
    elementOrigHeight = element.height();
    elementIncreasedHeight = Math.round(elementOrigHeight*(1+percent/100));
    if (elementOrigHeight % 2 > 0) { // odd
        // make sure increased size is odd too
        elementIncreasedHeight = Math.floor(elementIncreasedHeight/2)*2+1;
    }
    else {
        elementIncreasedHeight = Math.floor(elementIncreasedHeight/2)*2
    }
    elementOrigWidth = element.width();
    elementIncreasedWidth = Math.round(elementOrigWidth*(1+percent/100));
    if (elementOrigWidth % 2 > 0) { // odd
        elementIncreasedWidth = Math.floor(elementIncreasedWidth/2)*2+1;
    }
    else {
        elementIncreasedWidth = Math.floor(elementIncreasedWidth/2)*2;
    }
    elementNewLeft = -Math.round((elementIncreasedWidth - elementOrigWidth)/2);
    elementNewTop = -Math.round((elementIncreasedHeight - elementOrigHeight)/2);
}
```

Comment: The short answer is to write a plugin. See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring for style advice.

Comment: You can shorten `$(document).ready(function () {...})` to `$(function () {...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the global scope clean and to make this more reusable, create a jQuery plugin. This site has some good starting templates for organizing your code into a plugin:
http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/

Here is an example of your code as a plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/phil_mcc/VCUXY/

```
/**
* The pulsating plugin will make an element on the page pulsate.
* Sample usage: 
* $("#circle").pulsate({
        growInPercent: 100,
        durationGetBigger: 500,
        durationGetSmaller: 100,
        frequency: 3,
        pause: 3000
    }); 
*/
(function($) { //This function wrapper will keep all variables out of the global scope
    var PulsatingElement = {
            init: function( options, elem ) {
                // Mix in the passed-in options with the default options
                this.options = $.extend( {}, this.options, options );

                //save references to element
                this.elem  = elem;
                this.$elem = $(elem);

                this.setupHeightWidth();
                this.animate();

                //return copy for chaining
                return this;
            },
            //set default options
            options: {
                growInPercent: 20,
                durationGetBigger: 500,
                durationGetSmaller: 100,
                frequency: 3,
                pause: 3000
            },          
            setupHeightWidth: function () {
                this.originalHeight = this.$elem.height();              
                this.increasedHeight = Math.round(this.originalHeight * (1 + this.options.growInPercent / 100));

                if (this.originalHeight % 2 > 0) { // odd
                    // make sure increased size is odd too
                    this.increasedHeight = Math.floor(this.increasedHeight / 2) * 2 + 1;
                } else {
                    this.increasedHeight = Math.floor(this.increasedHeight / 2) * 2
                }

                this.originalWidth = this.$elem.width();
                this.increasedWidth = Math.round(this.originalWidth * (1 + this.options.growInPercent / 100));
                if (this.originalWidth % 2 > 0) { // odd
                    this.increasedWidth = Math.floor(this.increasedWidth / 2) * 2 + 1;
                } else {
                    this.increasedWidth = Math.floor(this.increasedWidth / 2) * 2;
                }
                this.newLeft = -Math.round((this.increasedWidth - this.originalWidth) / 2);
                this.newTop = -Math.round((this.increasedHeight - this.originalHeight) / 2);
            },
            animate: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.options.frequency; i++) {
                    this.getBigger(this.options.durationBigger);
                    this.getSmaller(this.options.durationSmaller);
                }       

                var self = this; //need a copy of object that can be referenced in the timeout
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.animate()
                }, this.options.pause);
            },
            getBigger: function (duration) {
                this.$elem.animate({
                    width: this.increasedHeight,
                    height: this.increasedWidth,
                    top:  this.newTop,
                    left:  this.newLeft,
                    opacity: 1
                }, duration, 'linear');
            },
            getSmaller: function (duration) {
                 this.$elem.animate({
                    width: this.originalWidth,
                    height: this.originalHeight,
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    opacity: 0.5
                }, duration, 'linear');
            }
    };

    // Object.create support test, and fallback for browsers without it
    if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
        Object.create = function (o) {
            function F() {}
            F.prototype = o;
            return new F();
        };
    }

    // Create a plugin based on a defined object
    $.plugin = function( name, object ) {
        $.fn[name] = function( options ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                if ( ! $.data( this, name ) ) {
                    $.data( this, name, Object.create(object).init(
                            options, this ) );
                }
            });
        };
    }; 

    //create a plugin called pulsate that uses the PulsatingElement Object
    $.plugin('pulsate', PulsatingElement);
})( jQuery );


$(function () {
    $("#circle").pulsate({
        growInPercent: 100,
        durationGetBigger: 500,
        durationGetSmaller: 100,
        frequency: 3,
        pause: 3000
    });
      $("#circle2").pulsate({
            growInPercent: 100,
            durationGetBigger: 100,
            durationGetSmaller: 500,
            frequency: 3,
            pause: 4000
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after some (more!) search on the net, I will propose one thing that I was already pondering about (having a little experience mostly with OOP languages Java and C#).
creating a **class/datastructure** to hold the values
I was inspired by these sources:

- [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190792/should-i-use-a-global-variable-and-if-not-what-instead-javascript)
- [answer nr 2 to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript?rq=1)
- [and this webmonkey explanation](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_oop_classes_in_javascript/)

still not sure if this is a **"better"** approach in JavaScript, but at least for my rather inexperienced eyes it looks more structured
the refactored version of my pulsating object is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RJWS2/11/)
the slightly changed javascript (find the class ElementWrapper at the end):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#circle');
    var growInPercent = 100;
    var elementWrapper = new ElementWrapper(element, growInPercent);

    var durationGetBigger = 500;
    var durationGetSmaller = 100;
    var frequency = 3;
    var pause = 3000;
    pulsate(elementWrapper, durationGetBigger, durationGetSmaller,
    frequency, pause);
});

function pulsate(elementWrapper, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
        getBigger(elementWrapper, durationBigger);
        getSmaller(elementWrapper, durationSmaller);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        pulsate(elementWrapper, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause)
    }, pause);
}

function getBigger(elementWrapper, duration) {
    elementWrapper.element.animate({
        width: elementWrapper.increasedWidth,
        height: elementWrapper.increasedHeight,
        top: elementWrapper.newTop,
        left: elementWrapper.newLeft,
        opacity: 1
    }, duration, 'linear');
}

function getSmaller(elementWrapper, duration) {
    elementWrapper.element.animate({
        width: elementWrapper.originalWidth,
        height: elementWrapper.originalHeight,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: 0.5
    }, duration, 'linear');
}

function ElementWrapper(element, percent) {
    this.element = element;
    this.originalHeight = element.height();
    this.originalWidth = element.width();
    this.increasedHeight = getIncreasedValue(this.originalHeight, percent);
    this.increasedWidth = getIncreasedValue(this.originalWidth, percent);
    this.newLeft = -Math.round((this.increasedWidth - this.originalWidth) / 2);
    this.newTop = -Math.round((this.increasedHeight - this.originalHeight) / 2);

    function getIncreasedValue(originalValue, percent) {
        var increase = Math.round(originalValue * (1 + percent / 100));
        if (originalValue % 2 > 0) { // odd
            // make sure increased size is odd too
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2 + 1;
        } 
        else {
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: you should use camel casing for functions in JavaScript - the only exception being constructors. So, your `ElementWrapper` is fine, but `GetSmaller` should be `getSmaller` etc.

Comment: @RobH thanks man, you're totally right, edited my post and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Going of drkthng's answer you can just have 1 global variable. Also it is good practice to declare all global variables at the top of a function using 1 var statement. This also brings a small amount of lines needed for initialization. But still room to change things

```
var Pulsate = {};
//Default values. 
Pulsate.durationGetBigger = Pulsate.durationGetBigger || 500;
Pulsate.durationGetSmaller = Pulsate.durationGetSmaller || 100;
Pulsate.frequency = Pulsate.frequency || 3;
Pulsate.pause = Pulsate.pause || 3000;

Pulsate.Pulsate = function (element, growInPercent) {
    Pulsate.elementWrapper = new Pulsate.ElementWrapper(element, growInPercent);
    for (var i = 0; i < Pulsate.frequency; i++) {
        Pulsate.GetBigger();
        Pulsate.GetSmaller();
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        Pulsate.Pulsate();
    }, Pulsate.pause);
}

Pulsate.GetBigger = function () {
    Pulsate.elementWrapper.element.animate({
        width: Pulsate.elementWrapper.increasedWidth,
        height: Pulsate.elementWrapper.increasedHeight,
        top: Pulsate.elementWrapper.newTop,
        left: Pulsate.elementWrapper.newLeft,
        opacity: 1
    }, Pulsate.durationGetBigger, 'linear');
}

Pulsate.GetSmaller = function () {
    Pulsate.elementWrapper.element.animate({
        width: Pulsate.elementWrapper.originalWidth,
        height: Pulsate.elementWrapper.originalHeight,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: 0.5
    }, Pulsate.durationGetSmaller, 'linear');
}

Pulsate.ElementWrapper = function (element, percent) {
    this.element = element;
    this.originalHeight = element.height();
    this.originalWidth = element.width();
    this.increasedHeight = getIncreasedValue(this.originalHeight, percent);
    this.increasedWidth = getIncreasedValue(this.originalWidth, percent);
    this.newLeft = -Math.round((this.increasedWidth - this.originalWidth) / 2);
    this.newTop = -Math.round((this.increasedHeight - this.originalHeight) / 2);

    function getIncreasedValue(originalValue, percent) {
        var increase = Math.round(originalValue * (1 + percent / 100));
        if (originalValue % 2 > 0) { // odd
            // make sure increased size is odd too
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2 + 1;
        }
        else {
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#circle'),
        growInPercent = 100;
    Pulsate.Pulsate(element, growInPercent);
});
```

Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N86tC/4/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't completely how I'd do it as I didn't want the changes to be too different. The main thing that I wanted to do was show you a different way of making your element wrapper. If you notice the way I have written it doesn't expose anything other than a getSmaller function and a getBigger function to the rest of your script. This is information hiding - only expose things to the rest of your script that you want other parts to be able to change:

```
var Pulsate = Pulsate || {};

Pulsate.pulsate = function(elementWrapper, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
        elementWrapper.getBigger(durationBigger);
        elementWrapper.getSmaller(durationSmaller);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        Pulsate.pulsate(elementWrapper, durationBigger, durationSmaller, frequency, pause);
    }, pause);
};

Pulsate.ElementWrapper = function (element, percent) {
    var originalHeight = element.height(),
        originalWidth = element.width(),
        increasedHeight,
        increasedWidth,
        newLeft,
        newTop,
        getIncreasedValue;

    getIncreasedValue = function (originalValue) {
        var increase = Math.round(originalValue * (1 + percent / 100));
        if (originalValue % 2 > 0) { // odd
            // make sure increased size is odd too
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2 + 1;
        } 
        else {
            return Math.floor(increase / 2) * 2;
        }
    };

    increasedHeight = getIncreasedValue(originalHeight);
    increasedWidth = getIncreasedValue(originalWidth);
    newLeft = -Math.round((increasedWidth - originalWidth) / 2);
    newTop = -Math.round((increasedHeight - originalHeight) / 2);
    getIncreasedValue = -Math.round((increasedHeight - originalHeight) / 2);

    this.getSmaller = function (duration) {
        element.animate({
            width: originalWidth,
            height: originalHeight,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            opacity: 0.5
        }, duration, 'linear');
    };

    this.getBigger = function (duration) {
        element.animate({
            width: increasedWidth,
            height: increasedHeight,
            top: newTop,
            left: newLeft,
            opacity: 1
        }, duration, 'linear');
    };
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#circle');
    var growInPercent = 300;
    var elementWrapper = new Pulsate.ElementWrapper(element, growInPercent);
    Pulsate.pulsate(elementWrapper, 500, 500, 3, 3000);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dVG7R/2/